# Make requestAnimationFrame work when page is hidden

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I have a website which uses `requestAnimationFrame` to constantly run a couple of functions. However, it won't run when the tab is hidden. I found a script online from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105348/16855745, but this only worked for setTimeout. I used the following: `requestAnimationFrame=function(t){setTimeout(t,1000/60)}`, which worked when paired with the above script, but I was wondering if there is any direct way to make requestAnimationFrame work when page is hidden.

Comment: No there is not. requestAnimationFrame is designed exactly to not run in background pages. rAF is for things that are to be painted on the screen, when in background nothing is painted on the screen.

Comment: Is there a way that I can override `requestAnimationFrame` to use `setTimeout` only when the window isn't visible?

Comment: setTimeout is also throttled anyway, so that wouldn't help you much, but yes, you can use the visibilitychange event to determine if you need a hackish timers that doesn't get throttled, like a Web-Worker based one, or an AudioScheduledNode base one.